# Covert a code to class

Tags: java, android, class

Can any one help me to learn how to convert a code to a class so I can use it every where?
for example I have this code
How can I convert it to a separate class and use it in my diffrent activities?

I am new with java and really have problem with this..Thanks for your helps

```
public  String getInformationData(String mySQL){
    String information_text=null;
    try{
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ClubCP.DbPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        Cursor information = mDb.rawQuery(mySQL,null);
        int information1 = information.getColumnIndex("description");

        while (information.moveToNext()) {

        String columns = (String) information.getString(information1);


        information_text =  "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'verdana';src: url('file://"+ ClubCP.SDcardPath+ "Homa.ttf');}body {font-family: 'verdana';color:#ffffff;font-size:18px;padding:10px 10px 0 10px;}</style></head>"+"<html Content-Type: text/html charset=UTF-8;dir=\"rtl\"><body>"
                + "<p dir=\"rtl\"  align=\"justify\">"                
              + columns
               + "</p> "
              + "</body></html>";
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(callingActivity, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
        }

    return information_text;
    }
```

Finally I created my class..I added another method to it but when I call it I get FC ..Where is my mistake?

```
package co.tosca.persianpoem;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class persian_poem_class {
     private Context c = null;
     private  SQLiteDatabase Db=null;
     private Activity callingActivity;
     //private Resources res =null ;

public persian_poem_class(Context c,Activity a)
        {
            // Constructor 
            this.c = c;
            Db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ClubCP.DbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            callingActivity=a;
        }

public String getInformationData(String mySQL)
        {
            String information_text = null;

            try
            {

                Cursor information = Db.rawQuery(mySQL,null);
                int information1 = information.getColumnIndex("description");
                while (information.moveToNext()) 
                {
                    String columns = (String) information.getString(information1);
                    information_text =  "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'verdana';src: url('file://"+ ClubCP.SDcardPath+ "Homa.ttf');}body {font-family: 'verdana';color:#ffffff;font-size:18px;padding:10px 10px 0 10px;}</style></head>"+"<html Content-Type: text/html charset=UTF-8;dir=\"rtl\"><body>"
                            + "<p dir=\"rtl\"  align=\"justify\">"                
                          + columns
                           + "</p> "
                          + "</body></html>";
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return information_text;
        }

public void Change_header(View v,String id){
            String path = ClubCP.SDcardPath + "/temp/"+id+"-header.jpg"; 
             Log.i("view binder", path);
           File imgFile = new File(path);
           ImageView img=(ImageView)v;
            if(imgFile.exists()){
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                         
                img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                 }
                      else    {                
                 img.setImageDrawable(callingActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.music_album_header_vinyl));

                 }
        }

public Cursor getData(String mySQL){

    Cursor c = Db.rawQuery(mySQL, null);

    return c;

}
public void closeMyDb()
{
    if (Db != null)
        Db.close();
    else
        throw new NullPointerException("No database selected!");
}
}
```

I call secound method by this code

```
persian_poem_class main = new persian_poem_class(Book_list.this);
ImageView header=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_header_book_list_activity);
main.Change_header(header, Peot_ID_for_db);
```

Again thanks for your time..
I fixed my class but now I have another problem with `Change_header` method..I get this error for `getDrawable(R.drawable.music_album_header_vinyl)` "getdrawable is undifined" I searched and I found problem is with scope but Cant fix it..I tried `c.getDrawable` but still have problem`enter code here`

Comment: Do you want to do this at runtime or compile tIme?

Comment: Sorry I didnot get your mean..I think your answer is in compile time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I made a simple class according your request but some section of your code is unclear to me like `ClubCP.DbPath` or `ClubCP.SDcardPath` that I think these are static variables.

Anyway to use this class you need to make new instance from `myClass`:

```
myClass mMyClass = new myClass(youractivity.this);
mMyClass.getInformationData("your query");
mMyClass.closeMyDb() // To close your current database
```

***Edited as per comment:***

```
import java.io.File;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class myClass 
{
    private Context c = null;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public myClass(Context c)
    {
        // Constructor 
        this.c = c;
        mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ClubCP.DbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }

    public String getInformationData(String mySQL)
    {
        String information_text = null;

        try
        {
            Cursor information = mDb.rawQuery(mySQL,null);
            int information1 = information.getColumnIndex("description");
            while (information.moveToNext()) 
            {
                String columns = (String) information.getString(information1);
                information_text =  "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'verdana';src: url('file://"+ ClubCP.SDcardPath+ "Homa.ttf');}body {font-family: 'verdana';color:#ffffff;font-size:18px;padding:10px 10px 0 10px;}</style></head>"+"<html Content-Type: text/html charset=UTF-8;dir=\"rtl\"><body>"
                        + "<p dir=\"rtl\"  align=\"justify\">"                
                      + columns
                       + "</p> "
                      + "</body></html>";
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return information_text;
    }

    public void Change_header(View v, String id)
    {
       String path = ClubCP.SDcardPath + "/temp/"+id+"-header.jpg"; 
       Log.i("view binder", path);
       File imgFile = new File(path);
       ImageView img = (ImageView) v;

       if(imgFile.exists())
       {
           Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                         
           img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
       }
       else               
         img.setImageDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music_album_header_vinyl));
    }

    public void closeMyDb()
    {
        if (mDb != null)
            mDb.close();
        else
            throw new NullPointerException("No database selected!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for your help..I added some codes to class but I have some problem..I updated my question..Can you help me about that?

Comment: @Majid Sure Majid jan, Where is your question? I can't see your updated question!

Comment: Oh I am happy to see you here,I will check it now,Thanks my friend

Comment: I checked your edit But my new method `Change_header` is not in it..now I have problem with calling this method in my activity..:(

Comment: @Majid That's because I did not add it, you can add it manually.

Comment: You mean I add that in my activity?But I want to use that method in all my activities..Or it is better for me to crate a separate class for that method too?

Comment: @Majid Nope, just add `Change_header()` to this class.

Comment: @Majid jan, Check my updated answer I added `Change_header()`.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a new class with a name that is descriptive of what it does (i.e. replace myClass with the name). Then, you create a constructor for this class by calling `public myClass()` WITHOUT a return type (this is how Java identifies it as a constructor. The constructor is what gets called every time the class runs, so simply paste your code in the body of the constructor, and it will get called every time you create a new object of the class.

```
  Class myClass {
       ...
       public myClass(){
          public  String getInformationData(String mySQL){
          String information_text=null;
          try{
              db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase ...
          ... rest of code...

    return information_text;
}

}
}
```

Welcome to object-oriented programming :)

Comment: Thanks man,I want to add some other methods to my class..So I think Its better to just add my opening database in constructor..Is this better?or not..Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simple create a new class by right clicking on your `src` folder and clicking create `new class`.

Once you've gone the through the process of naming your class, go and paste your current code into that class, which would be your `public String getInformationData(String mySQL)` method.

Once this has been done, create a reference to this class, be creating an object of this class in every class/activity you want to call `String getInformationData(String mySQL)` from.

```
YourClass foo =  new YourClass();
foo.getInformationData(string);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks dear Luke,I created my class and added new method but When I call It I get error ..Can you look at it?

Comment: What is the error, please post a full log and I might be able to help you. :)

Comment: I explayned in my question..(last paragraph) I even cant compile my file I get error for undefined method in  `getDrawable`